# my JS work on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my JS. I dont know why the "X" created by append to last child doesn't work on first click, but it does work on the second click. "x" url is in the cloned div. Is that causing the problem? Or is there something wrong in the HTML?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".add").click(function () {
        var aaa = $(this).parent("div").attr('id')
        $(this).parent().children(".add").siblings(".name,.detail,.price").clone().appendTo(".CART").wrapAll('<div class="dump ' + aaa + '"></div>')
        $(this).removeClass("add").addClass("added");
        $(".dump:last-child").append('<a class="delC" href="javascript:delC()">x</a>');
        $(".dump").removeClass("dump")
    });

})

////////////////
function delC() {
    $(document).on('click', '.delC', function () {
        var xx = $(this).parent("div").attr('class')
        $("." + xx + "").remove()
    })
}
```

```html
<div id="itemA">
    <div class="detail">USB</div>
    <div class="name">USB type1</div>
    <div class="price">1500</div>
    <div class="weight">20 Gr</div>
<a class="add">add</a>

</div>
<div id="itemB">
    <div class="detail">RAM</div>
    <div class="name">RAM type1</div>
    <div class="price">2000</div>
    <div class="weight">50 Gr</div>
<a class="add">add</a>

</div>
<div class="CART"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need a separate function to be called on href. You can just bind that to a click function.

```
$(document).on('click', '.delC', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var xx = $(this).parent("div").attr('class')
    $("."+xx+"").remove()
    })
```

Working JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j65uex6t/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are binding click event inside the `delC` function. So the first time you click you just bind events (and then you bind more and more event handlers)..

Instead remove `delC` function and just delegate delete events in the first place:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".add").click(function () {
        var aaa = $(this).parent("div").attr('id')
        $(this).parent().children(".add").siblings(".name,.detail,.price").clone().appendTo(".CART").wrapAll('<div class="dump ' + aaa + '"></div>')
        $(this).removeClass("add").addClass("added");
        $(".dump:last-child").append('<a href="#" class="delC">x</a>');
        $(".dump").removeClass("dump");
    });

})

$(document).on('click', '.delC', function () {
    var xx = $(this).parent("div").attr('class')
    $("." + xx + "").remove()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="itemA">
    <div class="detail">USB</div>
    <div class="name">USB type1</div>
    <div class="price">1500</div>
    <div class="weight">20 Gr</div> <a class="add">add</a>
</div>
<div id="itemB">
    <div class="detail">RAM</div>
    <div class="name">RAM type1</div>
    <div class="price">2000</div>
    <div class="weight">50 Gr</div> <a class="add">add</a>

</div>
<div class="CART"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buqqeg2c/1/)

```
$(function () {
    $(".add").click(function () {
        var aaa = $(this).parent("div").attr('id')
        $(this).parent().children(".add").siblings(".name,.detail,.price").clone().appendTo(".CART").wrapAll('<div class="dump ' + aaa + '"></div>')
        $(this).removeClass("add").addClass("added");
        $(".dump:last-child").append('<a class="delC">x</a>');
        $(".dump").removeClass("dump")
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.delC', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var xx = $(this).parent("div").attr('class')
        $("." + xx + "").remove()
    })

});
```